# Nonexistent Node version detected

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am having this weird issue:
[image]
As you can see, I *do not* have Node v16.11.1 installed in my computer, so I don't know why I'm having this notification in terminal. I can't create new projects and my current ones can't run either.